# Siri says "Sorry, but it looks like you haven't signed in to" when using AppIntentVocabulary phrases

Tags: ios, siri, development

I am implementing Siri `AppIntentVocabulary` to allow our app users to make audio calls e.g. "Hi Siri, Call Joe on MyApp".   I have added example phrases for `INStartAudioCallIntent` intent as necessary.  But when I try an example phrase, Siri does the following:

1. First it says "I'll need to access your MyApp data to do this. Is that OK?"
2. Upon pressing "Yes", it then says "Sorry, but it looks like you haven't signed in to MyApp".

I am unable to find any references of the same on the internet.   Wondering what exactly does Siri wants here to proceed forward.

PS: "Siri & Search > MyApp > Use with Ask Siri" is already enabled.